# How to increase number of columns when plotting multiple images in holoviews

Tags: python, visualization, holoviews

When plotting multiple images with holoviews in jupyter notebook using

```
hv.RGB.load_image('1.jpg') + hv.RGB.load_image('2.jpg') + hv.RGB...
```

the number of columns is limited to 4. I want to increase the number of columns so that i can put more images in one row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using the cols property for example set number of columns to 8

```
images = hv.RGB.load_image('1.jpg') + hv.RGB.load_image('2.jpg') + hv.RGB...
images.cols(8)
```